# Prove that the random walk X is null recurrent

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

I am having trouble showing the relationship of stationary distribution of this random walk.

**Question:**

Consider a random walk $X$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $p(1)=p(0)=p(-1)=1 / 3$ (note that $\left.p_{x, y}=p(y-x)\right)$. Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
T &:=\inf \left\{n \geq 1: X_{n}=0\right\} \\
q_{i} &:=P_{i}(T=\infty)
\end{aligned}
$$

Prove that the random walk $X$ is null recurrent by showing that it cannot have any stationary distributions.

**My attempt:**

**Edit**

With the help of Teresa Lisbon, I get that the recursive relationship is $$\pi(k)=\frac{1}{3} \pi(k)+\frac{1}{3} \pi(k-1)+\frac{1}{3} \pi(k+1)$$

This simplifies to the relationship of simple symmetric random walk where:

$$\pi(k)=\frac{1}{2} \pi(k-1)+\frac{1}{2} \pi(k+1)$$

I see that this is a first order difference equation with the answer given as $$\pi_{k}=a+b k$$ for some constants a and b. But now I am a bit stuck as I don't know what is the boundary condition.

Comment: Your transition matrix is doubly infinite : it should travel infinitely to the top right as well. So the equations you've written, I'm not sure they are correct. The correct equations are $\pi(k) = \frac 13 \pi(k) + \frac 13 \pi(k-1) + \frac 13 \pi(k+1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$. What you need to find is if any stationary distribution $\pi$ can satisfy this property.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Right. But wouldn't that just simplify to $\pi(k) - \frac{1}{3} \pi(k) = \frac{1}{3} \pi(k-1) + \frac{1}{3} \pi(k+1) = \pi(k) = \frac{1}{2} \pi(k-1) + \frac{1}{2} \pi(k+1) $ Isn't this just a simple symmetric random walk?

Comment: You're correct : it's a slowed down version of the simple symmetric random walk. A very similar argument for the simple symmetric random walk not having a stationary distribution would probably work here i.e. the fact that $\pi(k+1)-\pi(k) = \pi(k)  - \pi(k+1)$ is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly it is a slow down version of simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. So it is recurrent.

Consider the measure $\pi_i=1$ for all $i$. Then

$\pi_i = \frac{1}{3}\pi_{i-1} + \frac{1}{3}\pi_{i+1} + \frac{1}{3}\pi_i$,

which means $\pi = P \pi$, $P$ is the transition matrix.

So $\pi$ is invariant.

By Theorem 1.7.6 and Theorem 1.7.7 from J.R. Norris's Markov Chain, any invariant measure should be a scalar multiple of $\pi$. Since $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} \pi_i = \infty$, so there can be no invariant distribution, therefore the random walk is null recurrent.

Comment: thak you for that. I'm sorry but I just have a couple of stupid questions. When you say invariant does that mean stationary distribution? Also $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \pi_{i}=\infty$, this is because there are $\infty$ states?

Comment: Correct. For more information, you could refer to Norris's book.